# What's the difference between using render instead of respond_with/to in a Rails API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I am building a simple rails tutorial on how to build APIs for some students and I am building it without the respond_to and respond_with because I just want to see if I can build an api without using a gem. This is what I have and my tests pass:

controller:

```
class Api::V1::SuyasController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render json: Suya.all
  end

  def create
    render json: Suya.create(suyas_params)
  end


  private

  def suyas_params
    params.require(:suya).permit(:meat, :spicy)
  end
end
```

routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :vendors
      resources :suyas
    end
  end
end
```

tests:

```
require 'test_helper'

class Api::V1::SuyasControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "index can get all the suyas" do
    Suya.create(meat: "beef", spicy: true)
    Suya.create(meat: "kidney", spicy: false)

    get :index
    suyas = JSON.parse(response.body)

    assert_equal "beef", suyas[0]["meat"]
    assert_equal true, suyas[0]["spicy"]
    assert_equal "kidney", suyas[1]["meat"]
    assert_equal false, suyas[1]["spicy"]
  end

  test "create can create a suya" do
    assert_difference("Suya.count", 1) do
      create_params = { suya: { meat: "beefy", spicy: true }, format: :json }

      post :create, create_params
      suya = JSON.parse(response.body)

      assert_equal "beefy", suya["meat"]
      assert_equal true, suya["spicy"]
    end
  end
end
```

What's the difference between using render vs respond_with? I can't find any answers. Is there even something that I am doing wrong? Why are there two ways to create APIs (respond_to/respond_with AND this way?)

-Jeff

Comment: what problem are you facing?

Comment: What's wrong with the code from your perspective?  What errors are you getting?

Comment: Basically, why are there two ways to do this? What's the difference between my way and the other? My tests pass and everything... I just don't know both ways exist.

Comment: i found your previous question very similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31376472/creating-action-api-with-rails-do-i-need-to-use-respond-with

Comment: It is @Зелёный. Sorry about that but that thread didn't supply me with an answer I needed.

Comment: Are you looking for the difference between `render` and `respond_with`?

Comment: @Makoto yes! When would a developer use one over the other in creating a Rails api?

Comment: Okay then.  You should clarify what it is you're actually asking; as opposed to saying, "What's wrong with ___" (which will lead others to think that there's an actual code *problem*), you should state clearly, "When do I use ____ over ____?"

Comment: Noted. Changed my post for clarity. Thanks @Makoto

Comment: How do you render XML here? :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- **`render` is part of Rails** and it just renders whatever you say in whatever format you say. Typically a view, possibly a string, possibly a file.

  A pretty low-level function that renders whatever you say making a few assumptions per conventions, like where to look for a view.
- **`respond_to` is a micro-DSL** that allows you to respond differently to different formats being requested.

  I. e. in a block with `|format|` call to `format.json` requires a block that will be executed on requests for JSON, otherwise will be a no-op (no operation). Also, if `respond_to` didn't execute any block, it responds with a generic 406 Not Acceptable (server cannot respond in any format acceptable by the client).

  While it is possible to do `if request.json?`, it's not so readable and needs to explicitly specify when to respond with 406.
- **`respond_with`**, formerly part of Rails, now (since 4.2) in [a separate gem `responders`](https://github.com/plataformatec/responders) (for a [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998437/why-is-respond-with-being-removed-from-rails-4-2-into-its-own-gem)), **takes an object and uses it to construct a response (making a lot of assumptions**, all of them can be given at controller declaration).

  It makes code much shorter in typical use cases (i. e. some APIs). In not-so-typical use cases it can be customized to suit your needs. In highly unusual use cases it's of no use.

*I may be overly simplifying things, it's a general overview.*

Answer (score 4):

There are two things :)..`render` and `respond_to`.

**Render is used to create a full response and sends it back to the browser**.
So `render` is used in [respond_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to) ,to make your action very responsive for every call whether it can be js/ajax call,full page load(html),json(to show autosearch dropdown,tokens) or xml.So if i want my method to work and `respond` to every calls from client,i will use the below block in my action.

```
  respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(person_list_url) }
      format.js {render "show_person_details"}
      format.xml { render :xml => @people.to_xml }
      format.json { render json: @people}
    end
```

above controller will work on every scenario,such as js/html/json and xml  without getting `403 Forbidden error` which we get usually get when a js call is made to action having only `format.html` and not `format.js`

**HOPE IT HELPS**

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is that `render` only allows me to respond with JSON, whereas if I use `respond_to` and `respond_with`, I can respond in more than just one manner? Is that all?